# Convergence of infinite sums

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Assume it holds that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}a_n=0$ for a positive increasing seqeunce $a_n$. Can I say anything about the convergence of $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{a_k}$. More specifically, does it always hold that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{a_k}>0$ or can I find a counterexample where this equals to zero?

Comment: you can just replace $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ by $s_n$. having the $a_i$'s there just unnecessarily complicates things.

Comment: With the caveat that $s_{n}$ is an increasing sequence.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question.

Comment: If $a_n$ is bounded then $\frac 1 n a_n \to 0$. Why do you add this as an extra condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question has been edited. In the original question $(a_n)$ was supposed to be bounded.

Answer for the last part: if $a_n \leq M$ then $\frac 1 {a_n} \geq \frac 1 M$ so $\frac 1 n \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac 1 {a_k} \geq \frac  1M$. Hence there is no way the limit can be $0$.

For the revised version of the question take $a_n=\sqrt n$. In this case the limit is $0$ (because $\frac 1 {a_n} \to 0$).

Comment: Sorry, bounded was wrong, it was remainder from the previous version of the question

Comment: I have edited the answer. @AlexanderJI

Comment: Thanks a lot for  your answer. I just don't  understand why the fact that 1/a_n->0 is sufficient.

Comment: If a sequence $x_n \to 0$ then $\frac 1 n \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} x_k \to 0$. This is called Cauchy's first theorem on limits.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This clarifies it.